# NuSMV: difference between IVAR and VAR

Tags: models, nusmv

I know the difference between `IVAR` (input variables) and `VAR` (state variables) in `NuSMV`. However, I am able to understand the counterexample when `VAR` is used, but I am not in the other case.

Let me show it with an example.

```
MODULE main

VAR

  v1: 0..20;

  v2: 0..20;

  v3: 0..100;


INIT

v3 = 0;

TRANS

    ((v2+v1 = 0)  -> (next(v3) = 10)) &

    (!(v2+v1 = 0) -> (next(v3) = v1 + v2))

LTLSPEC
  G(v3 = 10);
```

The counterexample (clear enough) given by NuSMV is:

```
Trace Type: Counterexample 

  -> State: 1.1 <-

    v1 = 0

    v2 = 0

    v3 = 0

  -- Loop starts here

  -> State: 1.2 <-

    v3 = 10

  -> State: 1.3 <-

    v1 = 7

    v2 = 6

  -> State: 1.4 <-
    v1 = 0

    v2 = 0

    v3 = 13
  -> State: 1.5 <-

    v3 = 10
```

Now, change v1 and v2 to be IVAR.

```
MODULE main

IVAR

  v1: 0..20;

  v2: 0..20;

VAR

  v3: 0..100;

INIT

    v3 = 0;

TRANS

    ((v2+v1 = 0)  -> (next(v3) = 10)) &

    (!(v2+v1 = 0) -> (next(v3) = v1 + v2))

LTLSPEC
  G(v3 = 10);
```

The counterexample is:

```
Trace Type: Counterexample 

  -> State: 1.1 <-

    v3 = 0

  -> Input: 1.2 <-

    v1 = 7

    v2 = 3

  -- Loop starts here

  -> State: 1.2 <-

    v3 = 10

  -> Input: 1.3 <-

  -- Loop starts here

  -> State: 1.3 <-

  -> Input: 1.4 <-

  -- Loop starts here

  -> State: 1.4 <-

  -> Input: 1.5 <-

  -- Loop starts here

  -> State: 1.5 <-

  -> Input: 1.6 <-

  -- Loop starts here

  -> State: 1.6 <-

  -> Input: 1.7 <-

  -> State: 1.7 <-
```

Could someone explain why this counterexample is so strange? It has several nested loops. What does the output mean?

Answer (score 0):

Both counter-examples falsify the property in the very first state of the execution trace, so what happens next is somewhat not much relevant.

---

From the docs of `nuXmv`:

> **4.7 Traces**
>
> A trace consists of an initial state, optionally followed by a
>   sequence of states-inputs pairs corresponding to a possible execution
>   of the model. Apart, from the initial state, each pair contains the
>   inputs that caused the transition to the new state, and the new state
>   itself. The initial state has no such input values defined as it does
>   not depend on the values of any of the inputs. [...]

So a trace generally has the following structure:

```
S_0 | I_0 -> S_1 | I_1 -> S_2 | ... | I_{N-1} -> S_N
```

The idea is that a state `S_{k+1}` is obtained by applying inputs `I_k` over state `S_k`.

One can try using the commands `goto_state` and `print_current_state`, to navigate the counter-example and print each state's content. Alternatively, one may recall that `NuSMV` and `nuXmv` only print changing variables from one state to the next, so the execution trace should look like this:

```
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    v3 = 0
  -> Input: 1.2 <-
    v1 = 7
    v2 = 3

  -- Loop starts here
  -> State: 1.2 <-
    v3 = 10
  -> Input: 1.3 <-
    v1 = 7
    v2 = 3

  -- Loop starts here
  -> State: 1.3 <-
    v3 = 10
  -> Input: 1.4 <-
    v1 = 7
    v2 = 3

  -- Loop starts here
  -> State: 1.4 <-
    v3 = 10
  -> Input: 1.5 <-
    v1 = 7
    v2 = 3

  -> State: 1.5 <-
    v3 = 10
```

So basically after the first transition we end up in the same state forever with never-changing inputs and outputs.

---

You may want to contact `NuSMV` or `nuXmv` mailing list and mention this issue with the output routine.